# No copy multiplication in Eigen

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I'm using Eigen with big matrices and I'm thinking about ways to optimize my code, focusing on reducing dynamic memory allocation.

I'm trying to multiply two matrices. Those matrices change a little bit every now and then, but their sizes stay the same.

I'd like to see the output of the multiplication going to a predefined matrix (that would have memory already allocated for it).

So here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd   left, right,result;
// ... 
result = left * right;
// ... left and right values change a little
result = left * right;
```

And I'm looking for a solution that would be like that:

```
  void Multiply(
    Eigen::MatrixXd const&  left,
    Eigen::MatrixXd const&  right,
    Eigen::MatrixXd&        result);

  void Example()
  {
    Eigen::MatrixXd   left, right, result;
    // ... 
    Multiply(left, right, result);
    // ... 
    Multiply(left, right, result);
  }
```

The aim is basically to reuse the `result` matrix memory because in theory it should not change dimension. I was thinking about using `operator*=` but I kind of realize that it still needs an intermediate matrix to do the calculation.

Comment: Did you check that `result=left*right` actually reallocates when result already has the right size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`result = left * right` allocates a temporary matrix to hold the result of the multiplication, evaluates the product into the temporary matrix, and then copies the result from the temporary matrix to `result`. This is to deal with statements like `A = A * B` where a temporary matrix is needed.

If you know that the result is different from the matrices in the product, then you can write `result.noalias() = left * right`. Eigen will not use a temporary matrix in this case.

More explanation on aliasing in Eigen is at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html

Comment: Would that mean that `operator*( )` has different return types? how is that possible?

Comment: `operator*()` returns an expression object which stands as a proxy for the product, but it does not evaluate the product. The evaluation step is only done inside `operator=()`, when the product expression object is assigned to a matrix. Search for "expression templates" or "lazy evaluation" in C++ for more info.